# Google Plus SDK for iOS error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

Im trying implement "Google Plus SDK for iOS" on my project. But i have a problem like that.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: clean your project if still doesn't work try to add library again

Comment: Already tried so many times.

Comment: I tried and it works with charm :)

Comment: https://github.com/adamotte/googleplus-ios-sdk Are we use same library? :)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

Comment: Different url same result for me :( Im probably missing a Step Of Build Settings or Search Path or Framework.

Comment: are you using new project for this??

Comment: Yes im using new project for this. Only add SDK to my project.

Comment: I'm doing the same but it's working

Comment: I will transfer my all project to Google SDK Sample Project. I cant find another way. Thaks. :)

Comment: Try to run their sample project..